# How to enable graphics acceleration for SIS 771/671 on Zorin OS 8 lite (lubuntu 13.10)

Tags: drivers, video, lubuntu, graphic-card, zorin

Anyone knows how can I check/test my 2d acceleration? See if it's on/off and working correctly and as efficient as it should?

I have SIS 771/671 on Zorin OS 8 Lite. I believe the resolution should be better (it's 1024x768 right now and it looks a bit stretched horizontaly I assume 1024x1800 could look fine) and I feel video could go more smoothly and also I see some horizontal lines on the screen when playing movies.

So basically I think that the video driver is still not proper here. I found this instruction here at comment #230:
[sis drivers discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/301958)

I have a patch here :

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=xf86-video-sisimedia

btw the patch is for 13.04 - will it also work or be needed for 13.10?

Otherwise is there any other recommended lite distro on which SIS 771/671 could work fine and with acceleration ON?

Answer (score 0):

I had a notebook with this very same card back when Debian Squeeze was fresh.
I know this is super mad old and may not work on your case, but from every method I tried out there (dozens, just to keep in mind), only one that worked was this (for me and others on the community too).

It also will give a 1280x800 resolution, but will kill the VGA port (if it works).

First of all check your card (just to make sure haha).

`$ lspci | grep VGA`

It must show something like:
`Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)`

If that's right, proceed downloading the file 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6j58k0cctxix2q4/Driver-2d-Sis671-771-Debian6.tar.gz?dl=0

The file is in my dropbox for 4 years now, I think I won't delete it soon.

Decompress it using `$ tar -zxvf Driver-2d-Sis671-771-Debian6.tar.gz`

After that you'll need root permissions to copy the `xorg.conf` file to `/etc/X11/` and the `.la` and `.so` files into /usr/libs/xorg/modules/drivers .

After that reboot your notebook and try setting the new resolution.

This used to work fine on Debian and Ubuntu back in 2011. Now I don't really now, but everybody who tried this method reported it as working those days.

If it fails, sorry :( I tried my best.