# SiS 771/671 graphical card: Is there some Unix-like OS distro that works correctly with it?

Tags: debian, graphics

I have a SIS 771/671 graphical card on my laptop, and till now I've just got the conviction that it just does not works very well on Debian 7.0, Linux Mint 16, 17 and some old Ubuntu versions. From that [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164617/how-to-enable-graphics-acceleration-for-sis-771-671-on-zorin-os-8-lite-lubuntu/215280#215280) we see that I'm not alone and it does not works well on Lubuntu.
It's easy to deduce that Debian based system does not works good with that graphical card.
So, have someone a suggestion for some distro that may be more efficient with SIS 771/671?

Answer (score 1):

I recently refurbished a Fujitsu-Siemens Esprimo Mobile v5535 laptop (specs here: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Fujitsu-Siemens-Esprimo-Mobile-V5535.9149.0.html) which sports a SiS Mirage 3+ 672MX graphics chip.

The goal was to install some lightweight Ubuntu 18.04 variant (32-bit or 64-bit, Lubuntu or Xubuntu to be exact).

After trial and error for 2 days and lots of expired/non-working URLs in various forums, I found the correct driver for SiS 671/672 graphics.

The actual working driver is located here: https://github.com/rasdark/xf86-video-sis671

And I have created a bash script to help others on quickly installing the driver here: https://gist.github.com/fevangelou/46a2885233c45011ad5c8752f18eac73

Installed successfully with Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit and Xubuntu 18.04 64-bit (kept this one in the end).

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Putting Ubuntu Mate 20.04 on an old Packard Bell EasyNote ALP-Ajax C3 laptop (mentioning the model in case it helps someone in the future) I'd had no luck at all finding a driver, but this worked straight out of the tin!

Answer (score 0):

[Mageia](https://www.mageia.org) has working drivers for this card. You can even get them from there to use it a distribution which still uses X.org 1.15.

See the (Portuguese) blog post http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Configurando-SIS-67172-no-Ubuntu-1404.

Comment: I already tried that blog, and it's not Spanish, that is Portuguese.

Comment: Uh, that's embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

i have had antix 17.2 working with the sis graphics card on an esprimo mobile v5535

Answer (score 0):

I  was also struggling with same issue on friends laptop Fujitsu-Siemens Esprimo Mobile v5535 .

**Steps** :

- Install **xubuntu  18.04.1**:

  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/18.04/release/xubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
- Download &  unzip driver from  Portuguese  page   :

  https://static.vivaolinux.com.br/imagens/artigos/comunidade/sisimedia-0.9.1.zip

  it comes from https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Como-instalar-o-driver-da-placa-de-video-SiS-771671-no-Ubuntu-1804?pagina=2 
  ( it is similar to what  @Jodka pointed out but bit newer for ubuntu 18 04,  this page had important hint for me to test  solution from  person "hmslima" **+thank you "hmslima" and  google translator** ! oh and also thank you to **"TheSawage"**  who send this page in the comment from the @fevangelou script    )
- as admin run file manager    $>**sudo thunar** (or other file  manager)
- and  copy and paste the **xorg.conf** file from the unziped dir to the /etc/X11/ 
  and  copy **sisimedia_drv.la**, **sisimedia_drv.so**  to /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/   and restart laptop

  So Core finding  for me is  that you **have to stick with 18.04.1** Ubuntu/Xubunut/Lubuntu  versions if using above ZIP.  If using  newer   > 18.04.1   the  script  made by  @fevangelou will not work ,  also Portuguese blog posts will not work. At least i could not get it working  under Ubuntus 20.04 &  18.04.4  , also i raised the  issue for  driver developer(s) that @fevangelou   uses  in the  script
  https://github.com/rasdark/xf86-video-sis671/issues/6

  all the best,